# F# compiler directive for 'symbol not defined'

Tags: f#

Is there a way to specify that a symbol should not be defined, in an F# `#if` directive? Something like this:

```
#if not COMPILED
// do script stuff here
#endif
```

Though the above is a syntax error. The same thing is accomplished by

```
#if COMPILED
#else
// do script stuff here
#endif
```

but I wonder if there's a neater way?

(edit: I'm asking about the general case, not the particular case of COMPILED/SCRIPT. Sorry, I forgot to mention that from the beginning.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no neater way, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233195.aspx)

Comment: No offense to you or the OP but its clear that negating the semantics of the symbol leads to neater code. *(By avoiding the `#else` hack.)*

Comment: @ChaosPandion I agree, if it is possible, i.e. symbol is not used with original semantics elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @Robert - Yes, that's one unfortunate caveat but can be avoided by defining a new symbol like `NOTCOMPILED`.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - You could, but I think I'd rather stay with #if/#else instead. This could get messy pretty quickly. :)

Comment: @Robert - Well this is one aspect of programming that I find hard to get religious about. Quite frankly I don't even mind the empty `#if` clause but initially the OP seemed to really focus on overall neatness.

Comment: With two user defined symbols, e.g. DEMO and NOTDEMO, there are 4 possible cases and two of them are incorrect. If only one symbol, DEMO, and the empty #if are used, it will not be possible to create an incorrect case by mistake. So, I wouldn't define something like NOTCOMPILED.

Answer (score 4):

I would inverse the semantics of the symbol.

```
#if SCRIPT
    // do script stuff here
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who hits this question searching running interactive mode vs compiled executable:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r "YOUR_REFERENCE_HERE.dll"
#endif

//your code here ...  

#if INTERACTIVE
#else
[<EntryPoint>]
#endif
let main args  =
  //you code here ... 
  0 

#if INTERACTIVE
main null |> ignore
#endif
```